# Angular ngIf use @Output() result for condition

Tags: angular

I have a **card-list** component that should display elements of **card** component or **card-edit** component depending on if `wasEditClicked` on card component is true or false.

The template of the card-list component looks as followed:

```
<div class="loop" *ngFor="let guest of guests">
    <div *ngIf="true;else elseBlock">
        <app-guest-card [guest]="guest"></app-guest-card>
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <app-guest-card-edit [guest]="guest"></app-guest-card-edit>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

I would like to bind the ngIf condition to the wasEditClicked boolean.

My CardComponent (different from the Card-List component shown above) looks as follows:

```
export class GuestCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public guest: Guest;
  @Output() public wasEditClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.wasEditClicked.emit(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: `ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isWasEditClicked  = this.wasEditClicked .observers.length > 0;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a "wrapper" component that holds the edit and readonly version of a card.  It would have Input of guest a property of editClicked and a function called aFunction that takes a boolean.  inside aFunction you set editClicked to true/false.  so something like this:

```
<div>
 <app-guest-card *ngIf="editClicked;else #elseBlock" [guest]="guest" 
  (wasEditClicked)="aFunction($event)">
 </app-guest-card>
 <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <app-guest-card-edit [guest]="guest"></app-guest-card-edit>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

then in your top level component it would be

```
<div *ngFor="let guest of guests">
  <app-wrapper [guest]="guest"></app-wrapper>
</div>
```

what this allows is that a component only has to worry about one guest card instead of the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking it the wrong way : give a variable to your condition, let's say `showIt`

```
<div class="loop" *ngFor="let guest of guests">
    <div *ngIf="showIt;else elseBlock">
        <app-guest-card [guest]="guest" (onEdit)="showIt = $event"></app-guest-card>
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <app-guest-card-edit [guest]="guest" (onEdit)="showIt = $event"></app-guest-card-edit>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Then set the value when you click :

```
export class GuestCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public guest: Guest;
  @Output() public wasEditClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onEdit() {
    this.wasEditClicked.emit(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: you define showIt in GuestCard but try to use it in the condition in Card-List. That wont work I think

Comment: My bad, I read your code wrong ! I edited my answer, feel free to see it

Comment: Do you define showIt in the card-list component.ts file? My ngIf statement says the variable is not defined

Comment: You should not even define it, but if it gives you an error, you define it in the component that is **not** GuestCardComponent

Comment: That also doesn't work. (onEdit)="showIt = $event" Doesn't seem to do anything when onEdit in Card component is called

Comment: display the showIt variable, you will see it's value (unless you set it to true on init, then of course it doesn't change)

Answer (score 0):

I'm addign another answer because it's another solution.

What you can do is make a two-way binding, such as ngModel.

Here is how you do it :

```js
let emitValue = false;
@Output() public emitChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

@Input() get emit() { return this.emitValue; }
set emit(value: boolean) { this.emitValue = value; this.emitChange.emit(this.emitValue); }
```

Now in your HTML what you can do is

```
<app-guest-card [guest]="guest" [(emit)]="showIt"></app-guest-card>
```

Comment: And of course, you still use `showIt` in your *ngIf.

Comment: I get Can't bind to 'emit' since it isn't a known property of 'app-guest-card'.

Comment: My bad, I can't test Angular code on my computer, I'm writing it by memory. I updated my code, feel free to look at it again.

Comment: That still won't do it. Error: Decorators cannot be applied to multiple get/set accessors of the same name.

Comment: 2 out of 3 ... Now this should work. If not, see [this page](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)